# how to select 2 random category data

Tags: mysql, sql

My table struture is as follows (with data):

```
+------------------------------------+
|id    fname     category  city      |
|1     ram       cook      kathmandu |
|2     shyam     cook      lalitpur  |
|3     krishna   maid      patan     |
|4     jay       maid      kupondole |
|5     rajan     maid      ratnapark |
+------------------------------------+
```

The query should return 2 rows (cook and maid) at once with random cook and maid. How can I do this?

Comment: which database are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

**Two alternatives:**

```
(SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE category='cook' ORDER BY rand() limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE category='maid' ORDER BY rand() limit 1)
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5f89/4).

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
WHERE category IN ('cook','maid') 
GROUP BY category 
ORDER BY rand() limit 2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5f89/5).

Result:

```
ID  FNAME   CATEGORY    CITY
1   ram     cook        kathmandu
5   rajan   maid        ratnapark
```

Comment: thanks but i have tried it already but query is giving Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: @RabKo: Feel free to accept the answer. so that it could help others who come across with this type of doubts in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
select fname
from table
where category="cook"
order by RAND()
LIMIT 1
UNION
select fname
from table
where category="maid"
order by RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The sub query is responsible for finding the random id

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT round(rand()*(max(id)-min(id)+1))+min(id)
     FROM mytable
     GROUP BY category);
```

Comment: finding `the` random id or finding `two` random ids? The requirement needed two records